# Mongoose not saving data on update() to Mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add to an existing array inside my User object inside MLAB.

I am using Mongoose 5.1.1 and MongoDB 3.4.9 and I feel like Ive tried every single variation of update(), findByIdAndUpdate(), findAndModify() etc.

I am not sure why this update() method is not working. When I run this code, I get {"ok":0,"n":0,"nModified":0} in my raw response but no errors are being thrown. Ive read the docs and I believe I am running this correctly but clearly not.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

The User onbject in MLAB looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "Blah12345"
},
    "fbid": "123456789101112",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "My Name",
    "__v": 0,
    "guestlist": [],
    "reviews": []
}
```

My Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;
const schemaOptions = {
    collection: "users"
};

const Guestlist = new mongoose.Schema({

    guestlist: [{
        date: String,
        name: String,
        guys: Number,
        girls: Number
    }]


}, schemaOptions);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Guestlist', Guestlist);
```

My api file

```
import express from 'express';
import Guestlist from './data/guestlistModel';
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/guestlist', (req, res) => {

    const guestlist = new Guestlist();

    let date = req.body.date;
    let name = req.body.name;
    let guys = req.body.guys;
    let girls = req.body.girls;

    const query = {fbid: req.body.fbid};
    const update = { $push: {
        guestlist: {
            date: date,
            name: name,
            guys: guys,
            girls: girls
        }
    }};


    guestlist.update(query, update, (err, raw) => {


        if (err) throw err;
        if (raw) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(raw));
            console.log("1 document updated");
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create instance here ... you can use `Guestlist` directly

```
router.post('/guestlist', (req, res) => {

    let date = req.body.date;
    let name = req.body.name;
    let guys = req.body.guys;
    let girls = req.body.girls;

    const query = {fbid: req.body.fbid};
    const update = { $push: {
        guestlist: {
            date: date,
            name: name,
            guys: guys,
            girls: girls
        }
    }};


    Guestlist.update(query, update, (err, raw) => {


        if (err) throw err;
        if (raw) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(raw));
            console.log("1 document updated");
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    });
})
```